# How to suggest/recommend migrating a question to a different site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

[This question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6927/validating-conservation-laws-from-physics) is likely to be better served by physics.stackexchange.com. It is technically on topic for us, but the subject matter expertise required is more likely to be found in the physics group.

When I reviewed the question, I didn't see a way to suggest that it be migrated - is there a function that I've simply missed? (If so more fool me for responding when I'm half asleep). If not, what is the procedure to request that something move to a different stack exchange site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following screen. I don't believe it's mod only, but it might be. Do you not have all 5 of these options?

The third option brings me to a screen where I can enter a SE site to migrate to.

[image]

Comment: I don't recall seeing the option for another SE site. That could just be because it was way too early in the morning when I looked, though. I'll have to check again.

Comment: My suspicion is that they removed it from the standard view since on the beta sites, there are so few migrations, you can't draw a statistically significant sample of what sites to "pre-bake" a close-option. I'd continue a metaphor revolving around cookies and things, but I'd screw it up, so I'll just stop now. =]